# KDB - Temporal function results become input for function on subsequent row

Tags: kdb

I've been working with KDB to create temporal data from a set of inputs that represents segments functions of a model. The challenge I'm facing is that for a particular ID, there are be several segments where the last value of the temporal results from the first segment becomes an input (but not always) to the subsequent segment.

```
//Create sample table
t:([id:`AAA`AAA`AAA`BBB`CCC`CCC;seg:1 2 3 1 1 2];aa: 1500 0n 0n 40 900 0N;bb:150 200 30 40 10 15;cc: .40 .25 .35 .5 .35 .45; Fname:`Fx`Fy`Fy`Fy`Fz`Fz);
```

The simple dummy functions below return 5 periods of data but actually each function can return several thousand data points

```
//Dummy functions to generate temporal data
Fx:{[aa;bb;cc] (aa%bb)*(1-exp(neg cc*1+til 5))*100};
Fy:{[aa;bb;cc] (aa%cc)*(1*(1-exp(neg cc*1+til 5)))};
Fz:{[aa;bb;cc] (aa%bb)*(1-exp(neg cc*1+til 5))};
```

When I run the result for each function, we can see that where we are missing aa on a few segments.  The aa should be the prev (last t[result]) from the prior segment (i.e. `aa = 864.6647 for AAA seg 2` and `aa= 74.36035f for CCC seg 2)`

```
show update result:first[Call_Function]'[aa;bb;cc] by Call_Function from t

id  seg| aa   bb  cc   Fname result
-------| ----------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500 150 0.4  Fx    329.68   550.671  698.8058 798.1035 864.6647
AAA 2  |      200 0.25 Fy
AAA 3  |      30  0.35 Fy
BBB 1  | 40   40  0.5  Fy    31.47755 50.56964 62.14959 69.17318 73.4332
CCC 1  | 900  10  0.35 Fz    26.57807 45.30732 58.5056  67.80627 74.36035
CCC 2  |      15  0.45 Fz
```

I've played around with trying to reference the prior segment `prev(last(t[result])` but the list result isn't referential. Similarly, I understand the `/ (over)` iterator would be useful but I've been unsuccessful implementing it.

I thought about breaking this up into several steps (all the segment 1's then 2's then so on) and then append them all to a final table. Similarly, I'd like to keep track of each segments cumulative values and temporal counts(time) to pass to functions as limiters as well as so referencing the prev row successfully has multiple uses.

Ultimately, once populated, I'll ungroup the table to get it into an output similar to below which I could then re-sort if needed.

```
q)show ungroup t  
id  seg aa   bb  cc   Fname result  
------------------------------------
AAA 1   1500 150 0.4  Fx    329.68
AAA 1   1500 150 0.4  Fx    550.671
AAA 1   1500 150 0.4  Fx    698.8058
AAA 1   1500 150 0.4  Fx    798.1035
AAA 1   1500 150 0.4  Fx    864.6647
AAA 2        200 0.25 Fy
AAA 2        200 0.25 Fy
AAA 2        200 0.25 Fy
AAA 2        200 0.25 Fy
AAA 2        200 0.25 Fy
AAA 3        30  0.35 Fy
AAA 3        30  0.35 Fy
AAA 3        30  0.35 Fy
AAA 3        30  0.35 Fy
AAA 3        30  0.35 Fy
BBB 1   40   40  0.5  Fy    31.47755
BBB 1   40   40  0.5  Fy    50.56964
BBB 1   40   40  0.5  Fy    62.14959
BBB 1   40   40  0.5  Fy    69.17318
BBB 1   40   40  0.5  Fy    73.4332
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR I think the following is what you want:

```
q)t:update result:count[t]#enlist`float$() from t; // table extended to already contain a results column

q)applyF:{[t] update result:first[Fname]'[aa;bb;cc] by Fname from t where not null aa, 0=count each result} //applies each Fname function when needed
q)updateA:{[t]update aa:prev[last each result]^aa by id from t}; // updates column aa based on previous results
q)myUpd:updateA applyF ::; // helper function applying the two above

q)ungroup myUpd over t;
id  seg aa       bb  cc   Fname result  
----------------------------------------
AAA 1   1500     150 0.4  Fx    329.68  
AAA 1   1500     150 0.4  Fx    550.671 
AAA 1   1500     150 0.4  Fx    698.8058
AAA 1   1500     150 0.4  Fx    798.1035
AAA 1   1500     150 0.4  Fx    864.6647
AAA 2   864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    765.0526
AAA 2   864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    1360.876
AAA 2   864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    1824.904
AAA 2   864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    2186.289
AAA 2   864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    2467.737
AAA 3   2467.737 30  0.35 Fy    2082.149
AAA 3   2467.737 30  0.35 Fy    3549.414
AAA 3   2467.737 30  0.35 Fy    4583.378
AAA 3   2467.737 30  0.35 Fy    5312.001
AAA 3   2467.737 30  0.35 Fy    5825.452
BBB 1   40       40  0.5  Fy    31.47755
BBB 1   40       40  0.5  Fy    50.56964
BBB 1   40       40  0.5  Fy    62.14959
BBB 1   40       40  0.5  Fy    69.17318
BBB 1   40       40  0.5  Fy    73.4332 
CCC 1   900      10  0.35 Fz    26.57807
CCC 1   900      10  0.35 Fz    45.30732
CCC 1   900      10  0.35 Fz    58.5056 
CCC 1   900      10  0.35 Fz    67.80627
CCC 1   900      10  0.35 Fz    74.36035
CCC 2   74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    1.796406
CCC 2   74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    2.941846
CCC 2   74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    3.67221 
CCC 2   74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    4.137911
CCC 2   74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    4.434855
```

Now for a, hopefully not too long winded, explanation.

I'm going to make a couple of assumptions here:

1. Only column `aa` will have nulls
2. We can defer evaluating `result` for rows which do not yet have `aa` defined

For convenience I initiate `t` so that it has an empty `result` column

```
q)t:update result:count[t]#enlist`float$() from t;
id  seg| aa   bb  cc   Fname result
-------| --------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500 150 0.4  Fx          
AAA 2  |      200 0.25 Fy          
AAA 3  |      30  0.35 Fy          
BBB 1  | 40   40  0.5  Fy          
CCC 1  | 900  10  0.35 Fz          
CCC 2  |      15  0.45 Fz
```

and define a function that will compute `result` for any rows which have `aa` defined and which have not already be computed

```
q)applyF:{[t] update result:first[Fname]'[aa;bb;cc] by Fname from t where not null aa};
```

Now generating results is as simple as calling the fuction

```
q)applyF t;
id  seg| aa   bb  cc   Fname result                                     
-------| ---------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500 150 0.4  Fx    329.68 550.671 698.8058 798.1035 864.6647  
AAA 2  |      200 0.25 Fy    `float$()                                  
AAA 3  |      30  0.35 Fy    `float$()                                  
BBB 1  | 40   40  0.5  Fy    31.47755 50.56964 62.14959 69.17318 73.4332
CCC 1  | 900  10  0.35 Fz    26.57807 45.30732 58.5056 67.80627 74.36035
CCC 2  |      15  0.45 Fz    `float$()
```

To grab the next `aa` value from `result` you can do something like

```
q)update aa:prev[last each result]^aa by id from applyF t;
id  seg| aa       bb  cc   Fname result                                     
-------| -------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500     150 0.4  Fx    329.68 550.671 698.8058 798.1035 864.6647  
AAA 2  | 864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    `float$()                                  
AAA 3  |          30  0.35 Fy    `float$()                                  
BBB 1  | 40       40  0.5  Fy    31.47755 50.56964 62.14959 69.17318 73.4332
CCC 1  | 900      10  0.35 Fz    26.57807 45.30732 58.5056 67.80627 74.36035
CCC 2  | 74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    `float$()
```

We can simplify by writing another function for updating `aa`

```
q)updateA:{[t]update aa:prev[last each result]^aa by id from t};
q)updateA applyF t
id  seg| aa       bb  cc   Fname result                                     
-------| -------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500     150 0.4  Fx    329.68 550.671 698.8058 798.1035 864.6647  
AAA 2  | 864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    `float$()                                  
AAA 3  |          30  0.35 Fy    `float$()                                  
BBB 1  | 40       40  0.5  Fy    31.47755 50.56964 62.14959 69.17318 73.4332
CCC 1  | 900      10  0.35 Fz    26.57807 45.30732 58.5056 67.80627 74.36035
CCC 2  | 74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    `float$()
```

Now to get your desired result we will want to apply these updates over and over. Your instincts about the `over` iterator are correct here. The usage here applies the updates until the table stops changing (aka [converge](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/over/#converge))

```
q)myUpd:updateA applyF ::; // both update functions combined into one or convenience 
q)myUpd over t
id  seg| aa       bb  cc   Fname result                                      
-------| --------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500     150 0.4  Fx    329.68   550.671  698.8058 798.1035 864.6647
AAA 2  | 864.6647 200 0.25 Fy    765.0526 1360.876 1824.904 2186.289 2467.737
AAA 3  | 2467.737 30  0.35 Fy    2082.149 3549.414 4583.378 5312.001 5825.452
BBB 1  | 40       40  0.5  Fy    31.47755 50.56964 62.14959 69.17318 73.4332 
CCC 1  | 900      10  0.35 Fz    26.57807 45.30732 58.5056  67.80627 74.36035
CCC 2  | 74.36035 15  0.45 Fz    1.796406 2.941846 3.67221  4.137911 4.434855
q)(myUpd myUpd myUpd t) ~ (myUpd over t)
1b
```

And you can apply `ungroup` to the result above to get your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed walk through Jorge, very much appreciated to see it as a stepped approach. In my actual data, the column aa is actually both numbers and strings (which I have to cast and clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using over:

```
q)update res:{z .@[y;0;{y^x};last x]}\[0n;flip(aa;bb;cc);Fname] from t
id  seg| aa   bb  cc   Fname res
-------| ----------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1  | 1500 150 0.4  Fx    329.68   550.671  698.8058 798.1035 864.6647
AAA 2  |      200 0.25 Fy    765.0526 1360.876 1824.904 2186.289 2467.737
AAA 3  |      30  0.35 Fy    2082.149 3549.414 4583.378 5312.001 5825.452
BBB 1  | 40   40  0.5  Fy    31.47755 50.56964 62.14959 69.17318 73.4332
CCC 1  | 900  10  0.35 Fz    26.57807 45.30732 58.5056  67.80627 74.36035
CCC 2  |      15  0.45 Fz    1.796406 2.941846 3.67221  4.137911 4.434855
```

What I'm not clear on from your question is whether or not the "last value" is allowed to spill over from one id to a different id. If it shouldn't, you could simply add a "by id" to my solution

Comment: That is correct, each ID is discrete so adding the “by id” should work.  Looking forward to giving this a try!